# How can I change the GWT *.nocache.js file

Tags: javascript, gwt, linker

i'm investigating how to change the generated javscript code in *.nocache.js.
I'm trying to add a custom gwt linker to do that, but i don't know how to find such nocache.js files.

I tried it like this:

```
SortedSet<EmittedArtifact> emittedArtifacts = toReturn.find(EmittedArtifact.class);
for (EmittedArtifact emittedArtifact : emittedArtifacts) {
    logger.log(TreeLogger.WARN, 
        "++++++++++++++++++++++" + emittedArtifact.toString()
    );
}
```

but there is no nocache.js in the output.
So is there anybody has idea about how to locate the nocache.js with GWT linker or how to change this js at all?

thanks!

---

Ok, I found the solution by myself. The problem is I need follow the Linker guideline of new GWT version. I should use @Shareable and override another version of link function:

```
public ArtifactSet link(
    TreeLogger logger, 
    LinkerContext context, 
    ArtifactSet artifacts, 
    boolean onePermutation) throws UnableToCompleteException
```

Comment: please add your answer as a proper answer and accept it to close the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution by myself. The problem is I need follow the Linker guideline of new GWT version. I should use @Shareable and override another version of link function:

public ArtifactSet link(
    TreeLogger logger, 
    LinkerContext context, 
    ArtifactSet artifacts, 
    boolean onePermutation) throws UnableToCompleteException